# How can I follow my friend's location in MapView on a iPhone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I'm new to iPhone development. I'm working app like mapview and my question is how to display my current location in `mapView` and how to allow my friend so he can see my location in his iPhone mapview when gps is on. If someone has a tutorial, share link.

Comment: Way have you tried so far? Thus question is a little general. Why not attempt to solve this problem yourself, then post questions here when you get stuck at specific points.

Comment: hey,,,what are you doing now to perform your task?

Comment: i get data of latitude and longitude from server using json

Comment: +3 for you...now you can vote up too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send your current location to server and then you friend can get your current location from server using webService, then he can able to display on map.

Comment: means latitude and longitude of my current location?